# How to cast number to symbol in KDB?

Tags: kdb

A column has undergone a data type change, so the query has to be changed too:

Old query:

```
select from person where id = 100
```

New query:

```
select from person where id = `100
```

I'm new to Q and haven't been able to figure out how to do this:

Example:
I want to convert 100 to `100.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to convert to string first and then cast to symbol:

```
q)`$string 100
`100
```

However, having a numerical column as symbols is a **pretty bad idea**. Is this table being written to disk? If so this could possibly blow up your sym file and blow up your in-memory interned symbol list (increasing your memory usage).....assuming the numerical values are not very repetitive

Comment: I second with @terrylynch; A proper review should be done before finalizing a column with datatype symbol.